# trying to create a grid by user input with javascript and DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to make a grid with user input (ex. if they put 4 in, 4X4 grid.)

But I can't seem to make my code go down to the next row after it prints the 4th 'div'.

Any help would be appreciated, been stumped for days on this!

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
const container = document.querySelector('#container');

// Create boxes
function createBoxes (numBox) {

for (let i =0; i < numBox*numBox; i++){
    for (let j =0; j < (numBox - 1); j++){
        const square = document.createElement('div');
        square.setAttribute('class', 'box');
        square.style.width = '25px';
        square.style.height = '25px';
        container.appendChild(square);
        
    }
    
}
}


createBoxes(2);
```

CSS CODE:

```
.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
 }

.container {
width: 500px;
height: 500px;

}
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div id='container></div>
```

Comment: You should have a look at the CSS Flot and Clear rules. In short you create a container where you put your grid in. This is so wide that just 4 boxes will fit in. Then float will create the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css grid when working with grid layouts. Here is one way.
Correct your html to close the quotation mark in container.
Correct your css to be #container instead of .container.
The grid will calculate the width and height of each square inside the container equally.
Javascript

```
const container = document.querySelector('#container');

function createBoxes(numBox){
    container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${numBox}, 1fr)`;
    for(let i = 0;i < numBox*numBox;i++){
        const square = document.createElement('div');
        square.classList.add('box');
        container.appendChild(square);
    }
}

createBoxes(4);
```

CSS

```
#container{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: yellow;
    display: grid;
}

.box{
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to

- Correct your syntax for the container in the HTML; you're missing an ending `'`
- In the outer loop, create a row to put all children inside when in the inner loop
- Iterate only from 0 to `numBox`, then from 0 to `numBox`
- Use CSS to give each row a set height (and use CSS for the cells as well, instead of assigning to their styles in JS)

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container');

function createBoxes(numBox) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numBox; i++) {
    const row = container.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    for (let j = 0; j < numBox; j++) {
      const square = document.createElement('div');
      square.className = 'box';
      row.appendChild(square);
    }
  }
}


createBoxes(2);
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#container>div {
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```

If you don't like the doubling up of borders, you can use `nth-child` to, eg, hide the left border of all cells but the first in a row, or something similar, and the same sort of thing for top or bottom borders. (Or use a table and collapse the borders)

Answer (score 0):

Take it

```
<body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script src="./1.js"></script>
    </body>
```

```
const container = document.querySelector("#container");

// Create boxes
function createBoxes(numBox) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numBox; i++) {
        let div = document.createElement("div");
        for (let j = 0; j < numBox; j++) {
            let square = document.createElement("div");
            square.setAttribute("class", "box");
            // square.style.width = "125px";
            // square.style.height = "25px";
            // square.style.border = "2px solid red";

            div.append(square);
        }
        container.append(div);
    }
}

document.onload = createBoxes(5);
```

```
.box {
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 25px;
}

.container {
    min-width: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;
}
```